# How to write query for same table same index group

Tags: php, mysqli

combine one SQL queries from same table same index in PHP MySQL but i just try index name news image select table than than fetch this output   view.

this output view  image get to databese both are image but two two grouping view
how can its sole query throw

```
[first image get to databese][1]    [third image get to databese][3]  [five  image get to databese][5]    five 7 img ...............
[second image get to databese][2]    [fourth image get to databese][4] [six image get to databese][6]      six 8   img...............
```

but i try this query but no work

```
$numrow =0;
$vali=0;
$sql_q = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news where cat_id='$cat_id' and cat_id !=19 order by nid DESC"); 
$ny = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_q);
if mysqli_num_rows($sql_q) > 0) {
   while($newsRowi = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_q)){
            $row[]=$newsRowi;
   }
   $n=0;$val=0;
   foreach($row as $newsRow ){    
     $news_img     = $newsRow['news_image'];
     $f_id     = $newsRow['nid'];
     $news_heading = substr($newsRow['news_heading'],0,50);
     $sq = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tbl_news where nid='ny[0]'");
     $ya=mysqli_fetch_array($sq);
     $val = $ya['news_image'];
     $n++;
     $n++;
 }
?>
```

please help me

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, try to explain more briefly

Comment: In your query, `SELECT * FROM tbl_news where cat_id='$cat_id' and cat_id !=19 order by nid DESC`, you are using `cat_id` as string (`cat_id='$cat_id'`), and as integer (`cat_id != 19`). If is an integer, remove the quotes from the first occourence.

Comment: sir this id get to url throw i mean first image top second bottom and three top four bottom than all are image  in database view  this format continue all image view .